# Netsuite getting the display text for a formula

Tags: search, text, filter, formula, netsuite

I am in need of getting the text (display) value of a field to compare date ranges on the posting period.  I have the formula below I am pushing in to a filter array with other filters I need to run

```
var columns = [];
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('transactionnumber'));   
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('line'));
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('item'));
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('account'));
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('amount'));
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('vsoeallocation'));
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('postingperiod'));       
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('srctranpostperiod','revrecschedule'));
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('recuramount','revrecschedule'));
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('jedoc', 'revrecschedule'));

columns[0].setSort();
columns[1].setSort();   

var filter = [];        

var formula = "case when TO_DATE({postingperiod.displayname}, 'MON YYYY') >= " + newselectedDate.getFullYear() + " then 1 else 0 end";

filter.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('revrecenddate', null, 'after', newselectedDate));
filter.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('type', null, 'anyof', ['CustInvc', 'CashSale']));    
filter.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('templatename','revrecschedule','isnotempty'));
filter.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('deferredamount','revrecschedule','isnot', 0));
filter.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('formulanumeric', null, 'equalto', 1).setFormula(formula));   

var search = nlapiCreateSearch('transaction', filter, columns);

var searchresult = search.runSearch();
```

Which in theory would work except that it gets the value of that field instead of the text (it turns out to be a non date value).  I know there are ways once you have ran a search to get the text instead of the value (nlobjSearchResult.getText) but I have not found a way to do this within a formula.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can give the use case for your search?
It looks like you are trying to search for a transaction within a posting period.

Comment: Yes. Basically I need to filter out transactions within a certain posting period date.  I have to convert the posting period since its not stored as a date data type.  If line items within a transaction have a posting period that is not within the date range I specify I want them filtered out.

Comment: You need to create a function that would turn {postingperiod} to an actual date. Let say P01 15, you need to convert it to 01/01/2015 and concatenate it with your formula just like the selectedDate. The {postingperiod} field is not be convertible to a date.

it would like:

var formula = "case when TO_DATE(" + convert(postingPeriod) + ") >=" + selectedDate + " then 1 else 0 end";

function convert(postingPeriod){
//do your things
}

Comment: I do not think you quite understand what I am trying to do.  I've posted the block of code for you to review.   Your answer would work if I knew 1 specific posting period then yes I could just convert that and make it work.  I need my formula to look at each transactions posting period in my search and based on that posting period determine the date from after formatting the posting period.  Documentation I've seen online suggests that putting the field name in brackets in a formula will get the value of that field from the data I am searching on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that posting period might actually contain additional information that is apparently only used in functions like TO_DATE(). This may be because of the internal hierarchy of accounting periods. Or it might be because periods are List/Record fields in a single select box, so there is an ID for every posting period. To get around this, I've done the following (applied to your code):

```
var formula = "case when TO_DATE(SUBSTR({postingperiod},-8,8), 'MON YYYY') >= " + newselectedDate.getFullYear() + " then 1 else 0 end";
```

Which is basically adding a SUBSTR function to pick up the last 8 characters in the string to pass onto the date function.